# How to bring a branch from the original repository to the forked repository?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I had forked a repository few months ago. Now there is a specific branch in the original repository that I want to bring to my forked repository and want to do some experiments on that. I know how to get the current master branch of the original repository but I don't have any idea about how to bring some particular branch from the original repository. Please help

Comment: just fetch it and push it

Comment: Checkout it from the original repository and push to the forked, nothing special ‍♂️

Comment: In this particular case, the answer will be the same for GItHub and GItLab, but in general it's rare for both tags to be appropriate: pick the tag for the system you're using, not the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Add your upstream repo:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git
```

then create branch from that upstream

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout -b branchname upstream/upstream-branch
```