# How to get a branch from a forked repository after the fact

Tags: git

I'm working on a tutorial and the tutorial actually provided a Git repository, which one was to fork and work with. When I forked the repository, I only forked the master branch, as I assumed that's the only one I need.

The next assignment is to check out a specific branch from that repository, and I'm not quite sure how to do that.

I know that I can simply create a new repo and fork the whole thing again but that would throw me back to the start and somewhat disrupt the flow.

So what I tried is to add the source repo (provided by tutorial) as a remote (next to my forked repo), check out the branch, push it to my own forked repo and rebase it accordingly.

This didn't work.

I did add the source repo as remote and when I run `git remote` it is listed there. However, none of the branches are. When I use `git branch` all I see is my own master branch.

I also tried `git fetch -t source/branch` but that didn't work either.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73037174/how-to-bring-a-branch-from-the-original-repository-to-the-forked-repository) and it's basically what I tried but when I try to checkout I get this error:

```
# German
# fatal: 'source/branch' ist kein Commit und es kann kein Branch 'branch' aus diesem erstellt werden.

# English
# fatal: 'source/branch' is not a commit and  branch 'branch' could not be created
```

Is there any way to do this properly without starting from scratch by forking the source repo again? Why didn't my approach work?

Comment: Hi Benjamin. I wonder if I could trouble you to install an English spell-checker in your browser? I have seen a large number of misspellings in your posts recently, and that's after many have already been repaired in your posts.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief Stack Overflow is not a chatroom or a discussion forum, where posts are temporary. The purpose of the site is to curate a high-quality set of Q&A, which are as readable as possible for future engineers, and which are to be kept in perpetuity. For the most part this curation is a volunteer-led activity. It would greatly aid those volunteers if frequent posters were to strive not to create additional work.

Answer (score 1):

> When I use `git branch` all I see is my own master branch.

Correct, because `git branch` lists only *local* branches that you have *created*,<sup>1</sup> and you have not *created* any other local branches. But when you say `git branch --all` you see *all* the branches. You can then check any of them out locally.

I'll demonstrate (follow along on your machine if you like). I go to https://github.com/BLeeEZ/amperfy (chosen at random!) and make a fork where, making the same mistake you made, I choose to take only the `master` branch. I then clone my fork to my own computer, using the instructions that GitHub gives me:

```
% git clone git@github.com:mattneub/amperfy.git
% cd amperfy
```

Now, still pretending to be you, I realize that I needed all the branches; so I decide to add the original as a second remote. It is usual to call this `upstream` (not `source`) so I will do that:

```
% git remote add upstream https://github.com/BLeeEZ/amperfy
```

Now I have to `fetch` in order to get the branches from `upstream` (perhaps this is the step you forgot? You do not mention it anywhere):

```
% git fetch --all
```

Okay, so when I say merely `git branch` I see only my own `master` branch, just as you say:

```
% git branch
* master
```

But when I say `git branch --all`, there they all are!

```
% git branch --all
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/upstream/HysteriaPlayer
  remotes/upstream/develop
  remotes/upstream/gapless
  remotes/upstream/gaplessStreamingKit
  remotes/upstream/master
  remotes/upstream/miniPlayerNextButton
```

So you see, I do have all the branches from `upstream`, which is my second remote corresponding to your `source`.

Finally, let's say I want to check out one of these branches locally. I'll check out `gapless`:

```
% git switch gapless
```

Presto, I have created a local `gapless` branch corresponding to `upstream/gapless`. I could now, if desired, work with this branch and ultimately push it to my own fork:

```
% git push origin gapless
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You might say: So where did `master` come from? I never "created" it. Well, yes you did. When you `git clone`, Git kindly saves you a step by checking out the remote's default branch as a local branch, thus creating it for you. You can actually suppress that step when you clone (by saying `-n`), thus ending up with no local branches at all. That can actually be a very useful thing to do, and I do it quite often.